# Can't host a Minecraft server anymore

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

I have hosted Minecraft servers from time to time; I know how to do it.

Now suddenly people can't seem to join my server. I am talking about a LAN server now because I need to port forward if I want people from all over the world to join me. Before, everyone on my internet could join me. I used Hamachi so my friends could join me from their homes sometimes, too. Now people can't seem to join me, but I can join their servers.

This happened about 1-2 weeks ago now.

Can anyone please tell me either what is wrong or how to fix this problem? I would be so greatful if anyone could.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming.SE!  Your request that people also contact you via your YouTube channel was edited out because we want to keep answers and discussion in the community.  I see that it is already in your profile, which is how we recommend users do that.  You can also set up email alerts for when this question receives new answers or comments.

Comment: I suggest actually port forwarding instead of using Hamachi. I know Hamachi is now another company/name or something of the sort, so maybe that's the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Have you done any updates on your computer? Has your firewall/antivirus updated? Try and check your firewall settings and allow the games/ports for the games to see if that helps.

Comment: My firewall is not on. I have turned it off, and the game passed through just fine before it suddenly for some reason did not work. I will try to remember back to what kind of updates i did.

Comment: I have figured out something. I cannot turn my firewall on. It is deactivated, and i cant, for some reason, activate it. What am i gonna do?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar problem over a lan game - I couldn't connect to any game that my friends laptops were hosting, nor could they connect to mine.

It turns out that they were running Java 6 whilst I'd updated to Java 7. I downgraded to Java 6 and suddenly I could connect. (A host of other problems were suddenly sorted as well, apparently Java 7 & Minecraft don't like each other)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you didn't give your computer a static IP address when you port forwarded your router. When your internal IP address changes, no one else will be able to join your server because your router is sending their connection request to your old internal IP address.

Setting a static IP address is a moderately simple process. It is explained thoroughly with pictures on [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/).

Answer (score 0):

If you host with a different version then you are connecting with (1.2.4 vs 1.2.5) you will not be able to connect. this also applies for snapshots.

Comment: We are both using V1.2.5 and i am hosting a server on the version 1.2.4 (it is still working for my computer, but not for my brothers.), But it seems like something is wrong with my IP or ports... I have no idea so it would be nice if anyone with knowledge about ports and IP adresses please add a comment.

Comment: that'd do it. you can't host on one version and connect with another.

Comment: I worked before... with the same version... But i will download and try the newest version, even though i dont think it will work. If the problem was because of the server, my borther would connect and see the error screen, outdated server. But he could not connect to the server. I connected perfectly with 1.2.5 on a 1.2.4 server.

Comment: odd, it should have stopped you.

Comment: btw it is not only for Minecraft. It is for any game i have tried to play LAN now...

Comment: then it is either: the network, firewall, or settings changed on the computer acting as a server. I am leaning toward the network (probably port issue)

Comment: I believe it is my firewall... It has been messed up for quite some time now. Long time since i added this post. Anyways i am not launching a software that should try to detect the error.
Thanks for the help this far :)

Comment: If you are connecting to a different computer on your network be sure to connect to their internal IP. It is listed under Command Prompt > ipconfig > IPv4 address (do this on the computer you are trying to connect to).